# Non-linear clutch in VW UP!

Tags: vw, clutch

I've been driving a VW UP! for more than two years now and there is a question about the clutch that has been bugging me the whole time. Before this I was driving a VW Golf TDI and in this car when I pressed the clutch in I would get less and less engine braking until I had passed the friction point. It was the same with releasing the clutch, I would get more and more power until the clutch was past the friction point and out.

However, on the UP! when I press the clutch in the amount of engine braking goes up at first and then decreases until the clutch is all the way in. And when releasing the clutch I get the most power part way through the friction point and then less once it's all the way out.

Is this normal? I haven't asked my mechanic when taking it to be serviced, but he's never said anything was weird. It hasn't caused any problems other than the fact that is very difficult to do smooth transitions in this car compared to the Golf.

Comment: You wrote a very long story, but don't you just mean that the clutch acts more like an on/off switch and does not have a large area of travel where it gradually starts working?